# apache map single subdomain to folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, virtualhost

In my `/var/www` I have a number of sites (goodsite, badsite, uglysite). Right now they are accessed by `mydomain.com/goodsite`, etc..

What I want is for one site in particuar, uglysite, to be accessed by `uglysite.mydomain.com` - the others remain as they are.

I have tried all sorts of ways of fiddling with the.htaccess (in `/var/www`). Note I have mod-rewrite enabled and mod vhost-alias enabled.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^uglysite\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uglysite/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /uglysite/$1 [L]
```

**What ends up happening is that both mydomain.com and uglysite.mydomain.com always map to the same thing** (i.e., the index at `/var/www`). I tried adding in a new virtual host, and was surprised to find that uglysite.mydomain.com mapped correctly, but then mydomain.com also mapped directly to uglysite as well.

```
<Virtualhost uglysite.mydomain.com:80>
       ServerName uglysite.mydomain.com
       ServerAdmin www@localhost
       DocumentRoot "/var/www/"
       AccessFileName .htaccess
       <Directory "/var/www/uglysite">
               Order allow,deny
               Allow from All
               AllowOverride All
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The above was added to my sites-enabled/000-default file. This got uglysite.mydomain.com to work properly, but then mydomain.com mapped to the same thing!

Is there a straightforward way to do what I'm intending to do?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should be making uglysite into a second file instead of modifying 000-default

So, take a copy of the 000-default file, change the subdomain as you have done up there and modify the directory to /path/to/site

**000-default:**

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
       ServerName mydomain.com
       ServerAdmin www@localhost
       ServerAlias mydomain.com
       DocumentRoot "/var/www/goodsite"
       AccessFileName .htaccess
       <Directory "/var/www/goodiste">
               Order allow,deny
               Allow from All
               AllowOverride All
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**uglysite:**

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
       ServerName uglysite.mydomain.com
       ServerAlias uglysite.mydomain.com
       ServerAdmin www@localhost
       DocumentRoot "/var/www/uglysite"
       AccessFileName .htaccess
       <Directory "/var/www/uglysite">
               Order allow,deny
               Allow from All
               AllowOverride All
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also note that in the above samples, I have modified the `DocumentRoot` to point to the directory that you want file served from

EDIT: virtualhosts set to *:80 since your sites point to your own ip anyway

Comment: You should be making this file in /etc/apache2/sites-available btw and symlinking (`ln -s sites-available/uglysite sites-enabled/uglysite`) it into sites-enabled

Comment: Do I need to explicitly include it anywhere?

Comment: Dont forget to add the site to the apache.conf file and restart apache (`sudo service apache2 restart`) once you've finished your configuration

Comment: Depending on how you have your apache server set up, you may or may not need to include it in apache.conf.  Check to see if there is already an `Include sites-enabled/` line near the end

Comment: Unfortunately, now I'm at my original problem: now uglysite.mydomain.com works perfectly just as I wanted, but now mydomain.com also maps to uglysite.mydomain.com!

Comment: Did you make sure that the DocumentRoot is pointing to the appropriate directory in both configuration virtualhost files? Did you restart apache?

Comment: DocumentRoot is pointing to the correct folders. however, if I take the VirtualHost for *:80 and change it to mydomain.com:80 and reset apache - I get a slew of errors: "overlaps with VirtualHost ... the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive"

Comment: How many files do you have right now? Do you have something other than the two files I put in my answer? (is the *:80 in your default-000 right now?)

Comment: You may need to use the `ServerAlias` directive

Comment: Yes I have a virtualhost on *:81... How should I use ServerAlias (thanks for the help thus far)

Comment: Also, if you need to debug your configuration / see what apache is doing, try running the apache executable `/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -S` or `apache2ctl -S`